# Android: Can't seemed to assign variable with new value

Tags: android

I am having trouble with the variable: URL_STRING. I can't seem to add a value from another variable to URL_String. It just null for some reason. Your assistance would be appreciated.

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
ListView listView;
Spinner spinner;
EditText search;
Button bt;

String URL_STRING;
String entity;
String term;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
    term = search.getText().toString();
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> entityAdapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.Entities,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(entityAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

This is where I am having trouble. URL_STRING is still null

```
public void addURL(View view) {

    if(entity == "Select" && term != null){
        URL_STRING = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.url1),term);
        SearchDownloader searchDownloader = new SearchDownloader(this);
        searchDownloader.execute();
        listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else if(term == null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a search term",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        URL_STRING = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.url2), term, entity);
        SearchDownloader searchDownloader = new SearchDownloader(this);
        searchDownloader.execute();
        listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    entity = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    entity = null;
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see any concatenation, only assignment. What does the debugger say when you step through the code?

Comment: It says nothing. No error. It just says that my URL_STRING is null when I run it in debugger mode.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about the adapter and the array being assigned to it.

I have created something which are looking for, Kindly try this, code is available on [Github](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/spinner/list/activities/SpinnerTestTwoActivity.java) as well have a look at it if i may have missed something. to load the `imgae` I am using a `library` called `picasso` which you can easily import by adding following code to the dependencies block in the `build.gradle` file like this

```
 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

and you would be able to use picasso

```
public class SpinnerTestTwoActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner url_Spinner;
    private Button load_image_Button;
    private ImageView url_image_ImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner_test_two);


        initializeUI();
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        url_Spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerTestTwoActivity_url_spinner);
        load_image_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerTestTwoActivity_load_image_button);
        url_image_ImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerTestTwoActivity_image_from_url_imageView);

        String[] url_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.url_images);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, url_array);
        url_Spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        url_Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String image_url = (String)url_Spinner.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image_url).into(url_image_ImageView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

> activity_spinner_test_two.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/SpinnerTestTwoActivity_url_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SpinnerTestTwoActivity_load_image_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:text="Load Image"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/SpinnerTestTwoActivity_image_from_url_imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> url_images

This is the `array` which you will make in the `arrays.xml` file which is in the `res/values` directory

```
<array name="url_images">
    <item>https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7emgtQk5rdEE3bW8/style_icons_system_intro_principles_simple.png</item>
    <item>https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7MGhHV055eGk0R2M/style_icons_system_intro_principles_intuitive.png</item>
    <item>https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7MG80dmpHT0RidGs/style_icons_system_intro_principles_actionable.png</item>
    <item>https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7blViQzF0azNqZU0/style_icons_system_intro_principles_consistent.png</item>
    <item>https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7VXlvR05VSWhPZTg/style_icons_system_grid_geometry2.png</item>
    <item>https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7SUV1b2Z3b3NBazA/style_icons_system_best_do1.png</item>
    <item>https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7azQ4WThPb25NOGc/style_icons_system_best_do3.png</item>
</array>
```

> Output

[image]